# Rails has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Considering the following models, how can I select only the notes of students owned by a user? Also, do the models look ok?

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_notes
    has_many :notes, :through => :student_notes

    has_many :relationships
    has_many :users, :through => :relationships
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_notes
    has_many :students, :through => :student_notes
end

class StudentNote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :note
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :students, :through => :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: draw your relations out like a diagram. That helps me a lot

Comment: What snowYetis said. My question is why you're creating a separate User and Students table? Regardless, if you want to get back all of the notes from the students of a user, you're going to have to do it in a roundabout type of way. When you call User.students, you're going to get back an ActiveRecord Relation (which is essentially an array of all the student objects related to your user.) You'll have to set up another array, iterate through each of the students and then get back a list of their notes, and push their notes objects into this new array.

Comment: Another question - what is this Relationships table for?

Comment: You should use an has_and_belongs_to_many for n*n association (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). Your `StudentNote` model seems useless for me. There is some reason for this model exist?

Comment: Thank you all for answers. Relationship and StudentNote models are probably going to have additional attributes like 'status' and 'kinship'. Does it make sense that way?

Comment: @ccai Student model is not supposed to have authentication, thats why I have different models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your models cutting off `StudentNote`and `Relationship` and using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association instead.

To select only the notes of students owned by a user, you could add `has_many :notes, :through => :students` to your `User` model

Your models should look like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :notes
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students
    has_many :notes, :through => :students
end
```

And you could select the notes of students owned by a user this way:

`some_user.notes`

Comment: Thank's for answering. Like explained above, Relationship and StudentNote models are probably going to have additional attributes like 'status' and 'kinship'.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `notes` relation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :students, :through => :relationships

  # new relation
  has_many :notes, :through => :students
end
```

and query:

```
my_user.notes
```