# Filtering records by ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry about the title, couldn't come up with a better one to describe what I'm trying to do.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787459/rails-has-many-associations), some users suggested I could simplify the models. I didn't get anymore comments but I think I'm doing it 'the right way' because I need to store additional attributes in the join tables.

Anyway my models are setup like this.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_notes
    has_many :notes, :through => :student_notes

    has_many :relationships
    has_many :users, :through => :relationships
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_notes
    has_many :students, :through => :student_notes
end

class StudentNote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :note
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :students, :through => :relationships
    has_many :notes, :through => :students
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, in my note show view I have this:

```
    ...
    <% @note.students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to student.full_name, student %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    ...
```

This works, except I would like to show only the students that belong to current_user.
Any tips on how can I achieve it? I guess a helper method in the model would be the way to go, but I'm totally lost.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Student`:

```
scope :belonging_to, -> (u) { joins(:users).where users: { id: u.id } }
```

Then:

```
@note.students.belonging_to(current_user)...
```